# My phone don't use speakers to the maximum of its possibilities

Tags: audio, music, mp3, speaker

I've a Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro.

I've a problem with its speakers. When I put the maximum volume and I put the phone close to the hear, I found that my phone uses only half speaker to share the music(or every type of audio).

Is this a bond I can unlock in my audio settings or is this a problem that the phone has took from outside?

Comment: Using half of speaker to play sound? How can you know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disassemble the device, you will see that, despite the outer shell reserved a wide opening for sound output, the actual speaker unit is quite small and biased to one side. This will produce the effect you observed.

[image: desc]

You might be expecting a large speaker, or 2 separate speakers filling the whole opening, which simply can't be the case for lower-end devices.